# Ipad calls are not getting tracked in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

After setting the Static ip address in Ipad ,Net connectivity is working in ipad while Http proxy- manual section is not getting enabled ,in case Manual section is Enabled with fiddler configured machine as  server address, ipad prompts an alert service could not found

Thank

Xavier Milton.M

Answer (score 0):

Using Fiddler with iOS devices including the IPAD works just fine. http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2012/12/21/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices

In order for anyone to help you, you will need to revise your question to explain, step-by-step, what you've done in the IPAD's Settings and in Fiddler, and what you see.